# How many maximum markers add in Google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am working on a project which is include Google map & routes. In this App 2 or more markers & routes between them. So how many markers i add on Google Map & how many way points?

I found the solution. [Is there a limit on how many markers I can put on a google maps route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676979/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-markers-i-can-put-on-a-google-maps-route)

But i want this information for Google Maps API V2.Is this information same as a Google map API V3? If some limited waypoints are provided by google then how to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

> Google has also provided Marker Clustering techniques [Google
>   Clustering Technique for Marker on map][1]
>
> [1]:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering

Using this page, you can cluster markers in your application easily

Comment: Yep marker-clustering is awesome, yet Google's starts to lag heavily when you have more that 2000 markers. [This](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions) library handles more that 10 000 (10 000 is the number I personally tested). I read somewhere that it can take up to 20 000.