# how to create markers at different point between source and destination in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

```
{
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 12.8481608,
               "lng" : 77.632796
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 12.7033123,
               "lng" : 77.5885469
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2015 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "20.0 km",
                  "value" : 19950
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "40 mins",
                  "value" : 2383
               },
               "end_address" : "Unnamed Road, Billiganakuppe, Karnataka 562112, India",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 12.7033123,
                  "lng" : 77.5885469
               },
               "start_address" : "Unnamed Road, Bettadasanapura, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560100, India",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 12.8481608,
                  "lng" : 77.63232409999999
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.4 km",
                        "value" : 440
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 mins",
                        "value" : 128
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.844518,
                        "lng" : 77.6323664
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003ewest\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "_llmA_qyxM@`@@L@LBBB@H?N?RADAP?XCLCx@E|@Ez@Gz@Ez@EjEU~@Gb@C"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8481608,
                        "lng" : 77.63232409999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "30 m",
                        "value" : 30
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 11
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8443413,
                        "lng" : 77.6325708
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "gukmAiqyxMDERWHI"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.844518,
                        "lng" : 77.6323664
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.2 km",
                        "value" : 179
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 48
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8428057,
                        "lng" : 77.6328027
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "ctkmAqryxMFEDCHCHAJAL@|@BpAAZCN?HA`@ELS"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8443413,
                        "lng" : 77.6325708
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.1 km",
                        "value" : 132
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 57
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8416291,
                        "lng" : 77.63266949999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "qjkmA_tyxM@?DBD?|@BbBFP?D@H?F@F@HB"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8428057,
                        "lng" : 77.6328027
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.1 km",
                        "value" : 114
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 32
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8415124,
                        "lng" : 77.63163910000002
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "eckmAesyxMBH@D@F?F?H?HAZ?R?B?H?F@L@D@L@HBV@F@B@B"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8416291,
                        "lng" : 77.63266949999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "1.0 km",
                        "value" : 1008
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "3 mins",
                        "value" : 154
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8361958,
                        "lng" : 77.62500639999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "mbkmAwlyxM?@B@@@B@D@t@BhA@P?h@@J@VBJBFDFFJTJf@Lj@Nb@HRhAjClCzF@PFn@?V@TBPHXN^R\\PVLLJFZLd@Ll@Pb@NXRb@b@Vb@Vd@`@|@p@zAVf@DHJVVl@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8415124,
                        "lng" : 77.63163910000002
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "5.5 km",
                        "value" : 5453
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "10 mins",
                        "value" : 626
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.7963583,
                        "lng" : 77.61599439999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eBegur - Koppa Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by St Mary's Orthodox Church, Begur (on the right in 2.3&nbsp;km)\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "gajmAicxxM`@EPAN?VAP@XDd@F~@Nb@Bd@Ap@KnCc@vCc@h@CX?\\@RBPBZFh@L~Ab@z@Tt@RnA`@jBz@tDbBn@TjCdALDf@Jp@Nb@HP@r@HhBJtCBxBFhBJ`BJjER~FXj@Af@CRCHCTKLKHMJQXy@rBsG\\cAb@cAZo@l@y@TYd@e@dAmAx@y@bAiAt@u@t@y@XY^WNGLEJ?J@\\BPBf@J~@RjBT|AN`AFdAFf@?tE?bA?X@RB\\DJBv@F`BBdCBzD@|BF`ADvALjAJ|@Lf@DzFh@pALL@~@Jh@HtAThAL~BLp@@`AHbALdBXn@LTDNDJBJFJFLJr@t@`@f@Zn@f@|@b@p@\\^LLXTfAx@n@j@j@d@\\ZJZZfAVfADLbAzD`@vAnAzDN`@HRZr@\\x@\\v@lAvCNXHPFPN\\tBxExAdD"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.8361958,
                        "lng" : 77.62500639999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "3.1 km",
                        "value" : 3109
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "7 mins",
                        "value" : 395
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.7713362,
                        "lng" : 77.61348219999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Continue onto \u003cb\u003eKoppa Gate Nisarga Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Anjaneiya ( Hanuman ) Temple Nandanavana (on the right in 3.0&nbsp;km)\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "ghbmA}jvxMDJBDDFXNVFx@Xp@T|@\\r@`@h@ZpAt@|BrAhCrAhD|AjClARHRFPBTBbABlCFfB@`@AZGLIRO^c@z@u@d@_@d@YPIbC[TEhBc@t@MVCZEp@AJ?D?D?F?@@B?F@D?BBLF`@R|@ZD@B@@@B@BBBBBJBTBJDLDHBDDFFFTTVTFDFBVFTHJ@JBRBTB^DZ@zDZb@@n@@z@D^B~Ch@dGv@x@Nz@Pv@NTDF?D?D?FAD?BCFAFELIHWLUHGHGJADAF@rANnD^xGt@jDwFPWDIHIFEDCLALAL?T?V@N@RBTDLBJDXLZRNHB?B@LBL@D?B?D?BAh@Kn@Oj@IvAUx@O"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.7963583,
                        "lng" : 77.61599439999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.7 km",
                        "value" : 675
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 74
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.769209,
                        "lng" : 77.6181972
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "{k}lAg{uxMe@yACIKUEOESCK?G?E?K?OBUBU@GDa@LeBBU^}BBK@IFUFMDGDGLKHGJIJEDCDCFCFCHCHANCJArAIr@GTCLCFADCDABCBCBERa@`@aAHUBIBI@G?EEu@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.7713362,
                        "lng" : 77.61348219999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "48 m",
                        "value" : 48
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 6
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.7690771,
                        "lng" : 77.6186106
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "q~|lAwxvxMBA@C@C@C@C@EBG?EBOB["
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.769209,
                        "lng" : 77.6181972
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "8.8 km",
                        "value" : 8762
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "14 mins",
                        "value" : 852
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.7033123,
                        "lng" : 77.5885469
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "w}|lAi{vxMDCDA@?BAD?B?H?H?rDNpETV@bBJV@tBT~@Lx@LJBHDDBFDFDTZZXZPd@Nh@NdATjAVv@NhAL`BHLBJ@HBFDVLXNTNNHFBJBJ@d@DZ@j@Ah@EF?D@D?D@D@LFn@\\PLDDFFDDDHBF@F@J?LAZ?L?J@D?D@B?@@DFJHPFLLLDFZT^VB@LJ`@`@lA|AP^PTLPHJFHXNLHFDHBRHtBn@bAb@nBz@hBz@p@\\^PND^Jf@Jn@JXDxGfAzAPHDD@BD@BBL@P@J?H@R?p@Ad@@D@DBFJLNJTLp@ZXT~@fANL^TXFV?h@@|ABbBBbAF~BRdAFz@Bt@Dt@BV@PDPHJHZXJNRXBD@@@B?@?@?B?@?BAD?BGLINALAH@H@@@D@BBDLVDJBHDJDFBFNLbBtAhAx@FHDDBF@FBJ@JB\\@H@B@B?B@@@B@@@@DBd@ZlAx@j@^DDBBDF@B@DBD@FDJN^FJFJFJHHHFPJJD\\JNDNBTBJ@L@b@@p@@^@b@DL@L@PFXJTJPLPHRFTFB@D@HBH@F@F?^?v@A\\?^@VBRDl@HLBN@P@H?\\?L?JERG\\K\\KtBa@NEJAL?P@L@F@FBJ@PHPHjA^d@P^PXTVPZ`@TT\\\\ZT^Rv@^PFr@ZRFj@Jv@J~@N\\LTHBB@@@@@B?@?@@FAF?LCLEV?X?NBNH\\LZNNHHB@h@\\^VPLFBrAl@PLZVHFJHz@r@nAdAVVHDf@Rn@T`AZp@PhAZVFdBb@hCt@b@JX@`@?^BZ@TFVJf@Vb@PpA`@x@PbAFn@BJ@f@H`@FRFPDJFHFDFLRTXPRXRLFLDPBL@V@h@?X@P@h@H^HXB\\Bd@Dd@@VA`A?H?FAJAHCJCFCBCFEFIZk@N[f@eAV{@HUHQHMJKDCFCL?T@LDPFNDFDHDJJFHBFBF@H?L@N?L@PBNDHFFJDLBPBb@LRLPJRRNRVTZ\\nF`EJNHNFPJRNRPL|DlBd@h@ZVRL?@ZVx@hAVXJJHDJFNJ\\DX@\\BdABF@V@XBj@H`@Hl@Pj@Jh@Jl@FtALh@Dh@@R?`@?ZAjAA`@?`@@V@z@BjADh@@z@DT@f@BRBRDNBLFLFJFj@d@z@n@x@v@l@p@XXRXTVRZX`@LTPTj@l@JHFBvB|@n@Z|@j@XRv@d@HDDBPHJDHBJBNDVDh@Dp@HPBTDz@Rp@HhAPF@D@B@ZJr@Z`A\\zAh@ND"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.7690771,
                        "lng" : 77.6186106
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  }
               ],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "_llmA_qyxMBn@DPL@b@A~@IrDSbKi@b@CX]PONGTCjAD|BEj@GNSlDNh@BPDDN@b@A|@Dh@Hl@DFDBz@DpCDb@FNLV|@Lj@Nb@rA~ClCzF@PFfADf@Xx@d@t@XT`AZpA`@|@v@n@hArAxC`AvBzAIj@FdBVb@Bd@A`Eo@vCc@h@Cv@@d@FdATzCx@dCt@`H~CzDzAt@PtAXdAJhBJtCBbFRlH^~FXj@Az@G^OVYd@kApCwI~@sBbAsAhFwFjBoBx@q@\\MV@n@FfB^hEd@fCNzI@tBTfFFzD@|BFxCRhCXbK~@hGx@pDNdCVzDr@p@^tA|AbAlBb@p@\\^f@b@vBdBhA`Af@bB\\tAdBrG~A|E`BxDnBtEdFhLHLXNVFjBn@pB~@zBpA|BrAhCrAtHjDf@Pf@FpEJhC?h@Qr@s@`BuAv@c@xCa@~Cq@r@IhAATBx@^hA`@FDFNF`@JVf@j@^Z^J`ARlGf@nDL~Ch@dGv@x@NpCf@XA`@UVm@ROPCzAPhMtA|DoGNSLIZCb@?f@Bh@HXHt@`@d@N\\@hCg@pCe@i@cBQe@I_@?i@NuAP{Bb@iCH_@LUh@e@^Qj@MhDW`@K^o@r@kB@MAw@FOHc@B[DCFAVAfLf@zBLtDb@dAPNHNJp@t@`A`@nBd@bCf@hAL`BHXDPHvAv@RFp@FfA?p@EVD|@d@VRV^BRAh@@d@JVP^RTlAz@nB~Bb@t@V\\`@XTN\\LtBn@bAb@xEvBpAn@n@PjKdBdBVHFDPB\\@\\AvABJNTd@Xp@ZXTnAtA^TXF`A@`EFbEZ`CJjBHh@F\\Rf@h@Zd@?HIZK\\?RHPRb@HTHNrBbBpAbAHLDRDh@DTDFzBzAp@d@HJHVd@bAPTZRhAZrAHpABp@F^Hn@Vb@Vh@N\\HfB?|@@j@H|APf@?XEp@SrCm@ZG^@h@Hb@RpBp@x@f@VPZ`@r@r@z@h@|BbA~@RvBZx@\\BF?^Id@?h@Ll@\\j@vA`AXPdBz@lB|AfB|Ap@XpBp@zBl@jHlBz@@z@Dl@RjAh@pA`@x@PrBJhBZ\\LNNb@l@j@f@ZL^DlBD`CZjAFxAAPATE^Qb@u@v@aB`@qAR_@POTCb@F`@LPJRTFN@V@\\D`@LPXHt@Pd@XvAzAnF`EJNP`@Zf@nEzBd@h@ZVRNZVx@hAb@d@TLNJ\\Dv@DlADp@DlARxA\\vAR~BR|@@jDC`ELbDLf@H\\JXNfBtAfBhBl@r@h@r@f@v@|@bARLfDxAvA~@xAx@p@RdCXpAXzBZl@PtBx@jBn@"
         },
         "summary" : "Koppa Gate Nisarga Rd",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I am getting the above result message on calling google maps url...i am able to draw a route map between source and destination.

How can i ad markers at different points between source and destination.

i have tried some code by

```
   jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                    Log.d("in try",jRoutes+"");
                    Log.d("in try",routes +"");
                    /** Traversing all routes */
                    for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                        jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                        Log.d("jLegs",jLegs+""+"\n" +"");
                        List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        Log.d("path",path+""+"\n" +"");
                        /** Traversing all legs */
                        for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                            jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                            Log.d("jSteps",jSteps+""+"\n" +"");
                            /** Traversing all steps */
                            for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){

                                polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                                List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
                                position_lat = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("end_location")).get("lat").toString();
                                position_lon = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("end_location")).get("lng").toString();
                                list_lat.add(position_lat);
                                list_lng.add(position_lon);
                                Log.d("list", list+"");
                                /** Traversing all points */
                                for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                                    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                                    hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                                    path.add(hm);
                                    Log.d("latlng", ""+Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude));
                                }
                            }
                          Log.d("lat", list_lat+""); 
                          Log.d("lon", list_lng+""); 


                        routes.add(path);
                    }
                }
```

i am getting a list of latitudes and longitudes.how can i convert them to latlng and represent as markers in the map ?

Comment: Are you using the Directions API to get that JSON?

Comment: no i am using google maps api

Comment: What is the URL you query to get the JSON?

Comment: sorry it is the directions api..https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters

Comment: This might help, there are some good code examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/get-driving-directions-using-google-maps-api-v2

Comment: could you tell how can i make a marker move along the polyline between source and destination..like a busfrom source to destination..and not in straight line...along the route(polyline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Route Class. This is working code.

```
public class Route
{
    GoogleMap mMap;
    Context context;
    String lang;

    static String LANGUAGE_SPANISH = "es";
    static String LANGUAGE_ENGLISH = "en";
    static String LANGUAGE_FRENCH = "fr";
    static String LANGUAGE_GERMAN = "de";
    static String LANGUAGE_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED = "zh-CN";
    static String LANGUAGE_CHINESE_TRADITIONAL = "zh-TW";

    static String TRANSPORT_DRIVING = "driving";
    static String TRANSPORT_WALKING = "walking";
    static String TRANSPORT_BIKE = "bicycling";
    static String TRANSPORT_TRANSIT = "transit";

    static ArrayList<Polyline> Polyline ;
    static ArrayList<Marker> markerPrevious;

    public boolean drawRoute(GoogleMap map, Context c, ArrayList<LatLng> points, boolean withIndications, String language, boolean optimize)
    {
        mMap = map;
        context = c;
        lang = language;
        if (points.size() == 2)
        {
            String url = makeURL(points.get(0).latitude, points.get(0).longitude, points.get(1).latitude, points.get(1).longitude, "driving");
            new connectAsyncTask(url, withIndications).execute();
            return true;
        }
        else if (points.size() > 2)
        {
            String url = makeURL(points, "driving", optimize);
            new connectAsyncTask(url, withIndications).execute();
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public boolean drawRoute(GoogleMap map, Context c, ArrayList<LatLng> points, String language, boolean optimize)
    {
        mMap = map;
        context = c;
        lang = language;
        if (points.size() == 2)
        {
            String url = makeURL(points.get(0).latitude, points.get(0).longitude, points.get(1).latitude, points.get(1).longitude, "driving");
            new connectAsyncTask(url, false).execute();
            return true;
        }
        else if (points.size() > 2)
        {
            String url = makeURL(points, "driving", optimize);
            new connectAsyncTask(url, false).execute();
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public boolean drawRoute(GoogleMap map, Context c, ArrayList<LatLng> points, String mode, boolean withIndications, String language,
            boolean optimize)
    {
        mMap = map;
        context = c;
        lang = language;
        if (points.size() == 2)
        {
            String url = makeURL(points.get(0).latitude, points.get(0).longitude, points.get(1).latitude, points.get(1).longitude, mode);
            new connectAsyncTask(url, withIndications).execute();
            return true;
        }
        else if (points.size() > 2)
        {
            String url = makeURL(points, mode, optimize);
            new connectAsyncTask(url, withIndications).execute();
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    //

    public void drawRoute(GoogleMap map, Context c, LatLng source, LatLng dest, boolean withIndications, String language)
    {
        mMap = map;
        context = c;

        String url = makeURL(source.latitude, source.longitude, dest.latitude, dest.longitude, "driving");
        new connectAsyncTask(url, withIndications).execute();
        lang = language;

    }

    public void drawRoute(GoogleMap map, Context c, LatLng source, LatLng dest, String language)
    {
        mMap = map;
        context = c;

        String url = makeURL(source.latitude, source.longitude, dest.latitude, dest.longitude, "driving");
        new connectAsyncTask(url, false).execute();
        lang = language;

    }

    public void drawRoute(GoogleMap map, Context c, LatLng source, LatLng dest, String mode, boolean withIndications, String language)
    {
        mMap = map;
        context = c;

        String url = makeURL(source.latitude, source.longitude, dest.latitude, dest.longitude, mode);
        new connectAsyncTask(url, withIndications).execute();
        lang = language;

    }

    private String makeURL(ArrayList<LatLng> points, String mode, boolean optimize)
    {
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();

        if (mode == null)
            mode = "driving";

        urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        urlString.append("?origin=");// from
        urlString.append(points.get(0).latitude);
        urlString.append(',');
        urlString.append(points.get(0).longitude);
        urlString.append("&destination=");
        urlString.append(points.get(points.size() - 1).latitude);
        urlString.append(',');
        urlString.append(points.get(points.size() - 1).longitude);

        urlString.append("&waypoints=");
        if (optimize)
            urlString.append("optimize:true|");
        urlString.append(points.get(1).latitude);
        urlString.append(',');
        urlString.append(points.get(1).longitude);

        for (int i = 2; i < points.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            urlString.append('|');
            urlString.append(points.get(i).latitude);
            urlString.append(',');
            urlString.append(points.get(i).longitude);
        }

        urlString.append("&sensor=true&mode=" + mode);

        return urlString.toString();
    }

    private String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog, String mode)
    {
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();

        if (mode == null)
            mode = "driving";

        urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        urlString.append("?origin=");// from
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
        urlString.append("&destination=");// to
        urlString.append(Double.toString(destlat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=" + mode + "&alternatives=true&language=" + lang);
        return urlString.toString();
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded)
    {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len)
        {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            }
            while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            }
            while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)), (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String url;
        boolean steps;

        connectAsyncTask(String urlPass, boolean withSteps)
        {
            url = urlPass;
            steps = withSteps;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.hide();
            if (result != null)
            {
                drawPath(result, steps);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawPath(String result, boolean withSteps)
    {

        try
        {
            //Tranform the string into a json object
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
            if(Polyline != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Polyline.size(); i++)
                {
                    Polyline line = Polyline.get(i);
                    line.remove();
                }
                Polyline.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                Polyline = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
            }
            for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++)
            {
                LatLng src = list.get(z);
                LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);

                Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude)).width(4).color(Color.BLUE)
                        .geodesic(true));

                Polyline.add(line);

            }


            if(markerPrevious != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < markerPrevious.size(); i++)
                {
                    Marker marker = markerPrevious.get(i);
                    marker.remove();
                }
                markerPrevious.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                markerPrevious = new ArrayList<Marker>();
            }

            if (withSteps)
            {
                JSONArray arrayLegs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
                JSONObject legs = arrayLegs.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray stepsArray = legs.getJSONArray("steps");
                //put initial point

                for (int i = 0; i < stepsArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    Step step = new Step(stepsArray.getJSONObject(i));
                    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(step.location).title(step.distance).snippet(step.instructions)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
                    markerPrevious.add(marker);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {

        }
    }

    /**
     * Class that represent every step of the directions. It store distance, location and instructions
     */
    private class Step
    {
        public String distance;
        public LatLng location;
        public String instructions;

        Step(JSONObject stepJSON)
        {
            JSONObject startLocation;
            try
            {

                distance = stepJSON.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text");
                startLocation = stepJSON.getJSONObject("start_location");
                location = new LatLng(startLocation.getDouble("lat"), startLocation.getDouble("lng"));
                try
                {
                    instructions = URLDecoder.decode(Html.fromHtml(stepJSON.getString("html_instructions")).toString(), "UTF-8");
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ;

            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Call :

```
ArrayList<LatLng> allatlng = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(strDestlat), Double.parseDouble(strDestlng));
                    allatlng.add(latlng);
                    LatLng latlng1 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(strCurrentLat), Double.parseDouble(strCurrentLong));
                    allatlng.add(latlng1);

                    Route route = new Route();
                    route.drawRoute(googleMap, Home.this, allatlng, true, Route.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH, true);
```

Comment: could you please tell me how can i move a marker from source to destination along the route...but not in straight line

Answer (score 1):

You Can refer this code.

```
public boolean drawRoute(GoogleMap map, Context c, ArrayList<LatLng> points, boolean withIndications, String language, boolean optimize)
    {
        mMap = map;
        context = c;
        lang = language;
        if (points.size() == 2)
        {
            String url = makeURL(points.get(0).latitude, points.get(0).longitude, points.get(1).latitude, points.get(1).longitude, "driving");
            new connectAsyncTask(url, withIndications).execute();
            return true;
        }
        else if (points.size() > 2)
        {
            String url = makeURL(points, "driving", optimize);
            new connectAsyncTask(url, withIndications).execute();
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }


private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String url;
        boolean steps;

        connectAsyncTask(String urlPass, boolean withSteps)
        {
            url = urlPass;
            steps = withSteps;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.hide();
            if (result != null)
            {
                drawPath(result, steps);
            }
        }
    }




private void drawPath(String result, boolean withSteps)
    {

        try
        {
            //Tranform the string into a json object
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
            if(Polyline != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Polyline.size(); i++)
                {
                    Polyline line = Polyline.get(i);
                    line.remove();
                }
                Polyline.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                Polyline = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
            }
            for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++)
            {
                LatLng src = list.get(z);
                LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);

                Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude)).width(4).color(Color.BLUE)
                        .geodesic(true));

                Polyline.add(line);

            }


            if(markerPrevious != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < markerPrevious.size(); i++)
                {
                    Marker marker = markerPrevious.get(i);
                    marker.remove();
                }
                markerPrevious.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                markerPrevious = new ArrayList<Marker>();
            }

            if (withSteps)
            {
                JSONArray arrayLegs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
                JSONObject legs = arrayLegs.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray stepsArray = legs.getJSONArray("steps");
                //put initial point

                for (int i = 0; i < stepsArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    Step step = new Step(stepsArray.getJSONObject(i));
                    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(step.location).title(step.distance).snippet(step.instructions)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
                    markerPrevious.add(marker);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {

        }
    }
```

I tried it from this link 
https://github.com/tato469/Android/tree/master/routes%20googleMaps%20v2

Comment: Call drawRoute method as:                                           ArrayList<LatLng> allatlng = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
     LatLng srclatlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(strlat), Double.parseDouble(strlng));
     allatlng.add(srclatlng);
     LatLng destlatlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(strCurrentLat), Double.parseDouble(strCurrentLong));
     allatlng.add(destlatlng);

     Route route = new Route();
     route.drawRoute(googleMap, Home.this, allatlng, true, Route.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH, true);

Comment: could you please tell me what type is markerprevious

Comment: and i am getting error at Polyline also..whattype is polyline and where should i declare it

Comment: markerprevious and Polyline  are Arraylist. Delare it as global in your class as :    static ArrayList<Polyline> Polyline ;
static ArrayList<Marker> markerPrevious;

Answer (score 0):

From Json, your source and destination details are :

**Src** :

```
"northeast" : {
           "lat" : 12.8481608,
           "lng" : 77.632796
        },
```

**Destination** :

```
"southwest" : {
           "lat" : 12.7033123,
           "lng" : 77.5885469
        }
     },
```

So, we need to add two marker on map

```
jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

JSONArray jsonBounds = (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("bounds");
JSONArray jSrc = ((JSONObject)jsonBounds.get(j)).getJSONArray("northeast");
JSONArray jDest = ((JSONObject)jsonBounds.get(j)).getJSONArray("southwest");

String srcLat = jDest.getString("lat");
String srcLong = jDest.getString("lng");

String destLat = jDest.getString("lat");
String destLong = jDest.getString("lng");

LatLng srcPos = new LatLng(srcLat,srcLong);
LatLng destPos = new LatLng(destLat,destLong);

 Marker markerSrc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(srcPos
     .title("Source")
 );


 Marker markerDest = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(destPos
     .title("Destination")
 );

map.addMarker(markerSrc);
map.addMarker(markerDest);
```

**Update :**

```
  polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
  List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
  position_lat = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("end_location")).get("lat").toString();
  position_lon = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("end_location")).get("lng").toString();
  list_lat.add(position_lat);
  list_lng.add(position_lon);
  Log.d("list", list+"");
  Marker markerStep = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .position(new LatLng(position_lat,position_lon))
         .title("Destination")
     );
```

Comment: i wanted markers for end_location under json object steps

Comment: I have updated my answer.. you just need to add 2 lines under your `for` loop

Comment: i am getting error change type of marker step to MarkerOptions

Comment: That statement was my mistake.. please re-check my code answer.. thank you

Comment: thanku but,the markers are not displayed..please could you help

Comment: a route map is created between source and destination now the route is also not displayed..i want a new marker to move between source and destination along the polyline

Comment: Can you check my answer part again? This will work and show the marker along every legs endpoint

Comment: it is showing at every leg i.e Source and destination....but i wanted marker at every step end point or start point

Comment: You can add maximum 25 markers at a time on map according to Google Maps API.. if you show marker at every step then it will definitely gives you exception.. you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29181171/1994950 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6680503/1994950

Comment: i am using only 2 steps distance route...i am not getting any exception

Comment: i am getting exception as not in the main thread..i have added Marker marker step

Comment: Marker markerStep = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .position(new LatLng(position_lat,position_lon))
         .title("Destination") surround this block with try catch and got exception as not in main thread

Comment: could you tell how can i make a marker move along the polyline between source and destination..like a busfrom source to destination..and not in straight line...along the route(polyline)